# Difference between $\tt fft$ and $\tt dftmtx$ in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, fft, discrete-signals, fourier-transform, dft

I have the following MATLAB code:

```
audioFile= audioread('myFile');
%% Reshape according to the given distortion period
distortionPeriod = 512;
audioFile= length(audioFile) / distortionPeriod;
audioFile= reshape(audioFile, [newLength, distortionPeriod]);
```

I noticed the following difference:

```
 audioFileFft = fft(audioFile); % incorrect transform
 audioFileDftMat = audioFile * dftmtx(distortionPeriod); % correct transform

>> norm(audioFileFft - audioFileDftMat )

ans =

   1.2985e+03
```

Why this difference exist? I would expect that those two operation(`fft, dftmtx`) would give the same result, as mentioned by [MATLAB dftmtx's documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/dftmtx.html).

How can I use the `fft` and still get the same results I got using the `dftmtx`?

Comment: When you are computing the transform, what is the size of ```audioFile```? What is the value of ```newLength```?

Comment: @Engineer `audioFile=3000x512` , `newLength=3000`

Comment: @NaveTseva Your last code snippet (with `fft`, `dftmtx`) is not processing any signal at all! Please see my answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your resulting `audioFile` in the line `audioFile= length(audioFile) / distortionPeriod;` is a single number and not a vector signal.

And for this reason your `audioFileFft` and `audioFileDftMat` are computed from the processing of that number and not your initial signal vector in `audioFile`; which is not your intention. However if that line is for `newLength`, and this variable is an integer (i.e. initial `audioFile` length is multiple of `distortionPeriod`, here 512) then you can do this

```
audioFileFft = fft(audioFile, distortionPeriod, 2);  
audioFileDftMat = audioFile*dftmtx(distortionPeriod);
```

And the resulting `norm(audioFileFft - audioFileDftMat)` should be very small.

Answer (score 2):

The command `fft` computes the FFT along each column of its input matrix. If I understand correctly, you want the FFT along the rows. One way to do that is

`audioFileFft = fft(audioFile');`

The same can be done using the DFT matrix (albeit much less efficient):

`audioFileDftMat = dftmtx(distortionPeriod) * audioFile';`

Comment: Now I get it, tnx!